# What is the best way to parse this page using nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to figure out the best way to parse a search results screen that consists of 25 repeating chucks similar this:

> **Name:**  [JOHN DOE / COMPANY NAME](http://linktoprofile)
>
> **Status:** ACTIVE
>
> **Date Joined:** 2007-08-17
>
> **Address:** 123 MAIN STREET
>
> **City:** ANYTOWN  **State/Territory/Other:** NEW YORK **Country:** US
>
> **Postal Code/Zip Code:** 10101

I managed to parse and clean-up the page to return one of the 25 result sets and I'm stuck with how to return the rest.  I thought of implementing a variable that would increment from 9 to 33 but was unable to get it to work.  The code I'm using looks like this:

```
require "nokogiri"           

class String
  def astrip
    self.gsub(/([\x09|\x0D|\n|\t])|(\xc2\xa0){1,}/u, '').strip
  end
end

i = 9

f = File.open("testpage.html", "r:iso-8859-1:utf-8")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)

NAME        = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(1) a").text.astrip.split("/")
NAME_URL    = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(1) a").map { |link| link['href'] }
STATUS      = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(2) a").text
JOINED      = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(3)").text.gsub("Date Joined:", "").astrip.strip
ADDRESS1    = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(4)").text.gsub("Address:", "").astrip.strip
ADDRESS2    = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(5)").text.astrip.gsub("City:", "").gsub("State/Territory/Other", "").gsub("Country", "").split(":")
ZIPCODE     = doc.css(":nth-child(" + i.to_s + ") div:nth-child(6)").text.gsub("Postal Code/Zip Code:", "").astrip.strip

Output = NAME[0].strip, NAME[1].strip, NAME_URL[0].to_s.strip, STATUS, JOINED, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2[0].strip, ADDRESS2[1].strip, ADDRESS2[2].strip, ZIPCODE

p Output
```

It returns an output that I'm happy with that looks like this:

```
["JOHN DOE", "COMPANY NAME", "http://linktoprofile/johndoe", "ACTIVE", "2007-08-17", "123 MAIN STREET", "ANYTOWN", "NEW YORK", "US", "10101"]
```

Comment: Your sample text doesn't help determine how to access the various tags. Nokogiri parses XML or HTML, not text, so we'd need to see the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without sample HTML our ability to provide a working solution is really limited.

This should give you a starting point to work from:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p><b>Name:</b> JOHN DOE / COMPANY NAME</p>
      <p><b>Status:</b> ACTIVE</p>
      <p><b>Date Joined:</b> 2007-08-17</p>
      <p><b>Address:</b> 123 MAIN STREET</p>
      <p><b>City:</b> ANYTOWN <b>State/Territory/Other:</b> NEW YORK <b>Country:</b> US</p>
      <p><b>Postal Code/Zip Code:</b> 10101</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

data = doc.search('div').map { |div| 
  name               = div.at('//p[1]').text[/:(.+)/, 1].strip
  status             = div.at('//p[2]').text[/:(.+)/, 1].strip
  date_joined        = div.at('//p[3]').text[/:(.+)/, 1].strip
  address            = div.at('//p[4]').text[/:(.+)/, 1].strip
  city_state_country = div.at('//p[5]').text
  postal_code        = div.at('//p[6]').text[/:(.+)/, 1].strip

  city, state, country = (city_state_country.match(%r{City:(.+) State/Territory/Other:(.+) Country:(.+)}).captures).map{ |s| s.strip }

  {
    :name        => name,
    :status      => status,
    :date_joined => date_joined,
    :address     => address,
    :city        => city,
    :state       => state,
    :country     => country,
    :postal_code => postal_code
  }
}
```

The resulting output looks like:

```
require 'pp'
pp data
# >> [{:name=>"JOHN DOE / COMPANY NAME",
# >>   :status=>"ACTIVE",
# >>   :date_joined=>"2007-08-17",
# >>   :address=>"123 MAIN STREET",
# >>   :city=>"ANYTOWN",
# >>   :state=>"NEW YORK",
# >>   :country=>"US",
# >>   :postal_code=>"10101"}]
```

If you want an array of arrays, use this in the map block:

```
  [
    name,
    status,
    date_joined,
    address,
    city,
    state,
    country,
    postal_code
  ]
```

which will generate:

```
# >> [["JOHN DOE / COMPANY NAME",
# >>   "ACTIVE",
# >>   "2007-08-17",
# >>   "123 MAIN STREET",
# >>   "ANYTOWN",
# >>   "NEW YORK",
# >>   "US",
# >>   "10101"]]
```

An alternate way to do the lookups, which I think is easier to maintain because it's more DRY, is:

```
data = doc.search('div').map { |div| 
  name,
  status,
  date_joined,
  address,
  city,
  state,
  country,
  postal_code = [
    'Name', 
    'Status', 
    'Date Joined', 
    'Address', 
    'City', 
    'State/Territory/Other', 
    'Country', 
    'Postal Code/Zip Code'
  ].map { |t| 
     div.at( %Q(//p/b[text()="#{t}:"]) ).next.text.strip
  }
```